# How can i package helm to an KOPS installed Cluster on AWS

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kops

I have installed an Kubernetes Cluster via KOPS on AWS. Everything works fine. But there is no HELM installed in the Cluster. I found no information how i can install it with KOPS.

How do i install it with KOPS to the Cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You install the helm client first on your local machine and then use it to install tiller into the cluster with `helm init`. So you need to set up the cluster first. The helm client doesn't need to know what type of cluster you have in order to install tiller - it just needs to you have to access to the cluster configured in your kube config. So first you set up the cluster and then the [official helm installation guide is applicable](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/install.md)